# Visual Studio Code Jupyter not recognising conda kernel

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kernel, jupyter, conda

I created a new conda environment named 'ct' and installed Python 3.10.6, Jupyter Lab, matplotlib and numpy. Also the ipykernel is installed.

VS Code lets me select Python 3.10.6 from 'ct' as interpreter without issues.

[VS Code select interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld5sg.png)

But I cannot choose 'ct' as kernel as VS Code only suggests the 'base' kernel from conda. 'base' does not have the desired packages installed which leads to the following error when running this code:

```
import matplotlib as mat
print(mat.__version__)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 1 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import matplotlib as mat
      2 print(mat.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

**This is actually totally fine** but I don't get why the 'ct' kernel is not showing up in the list when trying to change the kernel.

[Cannot choose kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR7Hr.png)

Also when running jupyter lab in browser from 'ct' environment everything is working as should.

When listing all installed packages in 'ct' in the VS Code terminal all packages show up.

Restarting VS Code and trying with other new conda environments does not help the issue.

Did I somehow miss something?

Comment: I have the same problem - new environments immediately show up as available interpreters but not kernels. In the past it seemed like vs code would allow me to select an environment even if it didn't have ipykernel installed and would prompt me to install it upon running a cell, but that doesn't seem to be the case anymore

Comment: same issue as @Zac

Comment: also, can confirm that switching to "pre-release version" of jupyter extension in vscode solves this issue immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally worked out for me was closing VS Code entirely, recreating the environment and creating a new blank notebook in VS Code. Now the kernel shows up and is surprisingly available for all new and old notebooks.

I also found this option in the Jupyter settings in VS Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcJU6.png

I haven't tried it yet, but it might be helpful to someone experiencing similar issues.

Also Zac's solution above might be super helpful. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Switching to the "pre-release" version of the Jupyter extension immediately solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by opening the directory in VS Code, instead of only the `.ipynb` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `conda install -n meta_ai ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall`
Somehow it solved my problems.
If it still can't solve your problem, try also opening the directory in VS Code, instead of only the .ipynb file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Obviously, this is not a universal problem.

You can read the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-conda-environment) and **recreate** the conda environment.

This may also be related to the fact that your conda environment is **not activated**. Use the command `conda activate ct` to activate it.

Comment: I recreated the environment several times and of course, activated it but it still didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out an alternative. The steps are:

- I have created my conda environment as usual using the CLI of VSCode.
- Then, I close the VSCode window and open a new one (or a terminal, it doesn't matter).
- In the terminal I activate my conda environment.
- I execute the `code` command which opens a VSCode.
- Then when selecting kernels (top-right of the window with a Jupyter Notebook opened, attached screenshot), VSCode automatically detects the conda environment.

This worked for me after trying several alternatives. A prerequisite is obviously to have the jupyter extension installed in VSCode.

[image: Kernel selector]